# SQL Server 2008 State:23000,Code:2627,Error:Violation of PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, constraints, primary-key, unique-constraint

I have a database with a table `mediainteraction` with 10 records: 1 to 10

I have imported data from another table and now it has 20 records: 11 to 20

When system tries to create a new record I received this error:

> State:23000,Code:2627,Error:Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'pk120_mediainteraction_pkey'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.mediainteraction'. The duplicate key value is (11).

It seems like if the system is trying to create new record with pkey 11 instead of 21.

Comment: Are you leveraging auto-seeding of your primary key field or are you forcing inserts on that column? What does your insert query look like?

Comment: Can you please show us the **table structure** and how you're trying to insert the new rows?

Comment: My query: 
insert into  destination.dbo.mediainteraction (pkey,field1....fieldn)
select pkey,field1....fieldn
from source.dbo.mediainteraction

Comment: You're selecting out of your origin table to then insert into the same table? Without, as you mentioned below, having automatically incrementing values on your PK column?

Comment: Hello. Not he same table. Two tables with same name but located in different servers.

Answer (score 1):

The table was probably filled with Fast Load - Keep Identity option, or this clause was used:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT table ON
```

This caused the table to accept identity values from another table and not creating its own values. So current identity of the table is lower that already existing values, and adding new rows causes this error.

Check current identity with:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('mediainteraction', NORESEED)
```

An fix the problem using:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('mediainteraction')
```

Or specify own current identity value leaving the gap:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('mediainteraction', RESEED, 100)
```

Comment: When checking identity I recieve: Msg 7997, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
'mediainteraction' does not contain an identity column.